# Function not found tensorflow lite get_top_n

Tags: c++, tensorflow, qt-creator, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to use an "example" code for c++ on qt. In this example, there's a function "get_top_n" from `tflite::label_image`, in `tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/get_top_n.h`. But, qt creator doesn't find the function.

Error: `main.cpp:104 (and 107): erreur : no matching function for call to 'get_top_n'`

What am I doing wrong here ?

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/string_util.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/get_top_n.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/model.h"

std::vector<std::string> load_labels(std::string labels_file)
{
    std::ifstream file(labels_file.c_str());
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open label file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    std::string label_str;
    std::vector<std::string> labels;

    while (std::getline(file, label_str))
    {
        if (label_str.size() > 0)
            labels.push_back(label_str);
    }
    file.close();
    return labels;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Get Model label and input image
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "TfliteClassification.exe modelfile labels image\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    const char *modelFileName = argv[1];
    const char *labelFile = argv[2];
    const char *imageFile = argv[3];

    // Load Model
    auto model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(modelFileName);
    if (model == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to load model\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Initiate Interpreter
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);
    if (interpreter == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initiate the interpreter\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate tensor\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Configure the interpreter
    interpreter->SetAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(true);
    interpreter->SetNumThreads(1);
    // Get Input Tensor Dimensions
    int input = interpreter->inputs()[0];
    auto height = interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[1];
    auto width = interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[2];
    auto channels = interpreter->tensor(input)->dims->data[3];
    // Load Input Image
    cv::Mat image;
    auto frame = cv::imread(imageFile);
    if (frame.empty())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load iamge\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Copy image to input tensor
    cv::resize(frame, image, cv::Size(width, height), cv::INTER_NEAREST);
    memcpy(interpreter->typed_input_tensor<unsigned char>(0), image.data, image.total() * image.elemSize());

    // Inference
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, end;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    interpreter->Invoke();
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto inference_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    // Get Output
    int output = interpreter->outputs()[0];
    TfLiteIntArray *output_dims = interpreter->tensor(output)->dims;
    auto output_size = output_dims->data[output_dims->size - 1];
    std::vector<std::pair<float, int>> top_results;
    float threshold = 0.01f;

    switch (interpreter->tensor(output)->type)
    {
    case kTfLiteInt32:
        tflite::label_image::get_top_n<float>(interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0), output_size, 1, threshold, &top_results, kTfLiteFloat32);
        break;
    case kTfLiteUInt8:
        tflite::label_image::get_top_n<uint8_t>(interpreter->typed_output_tensor<uint8_t>(0), output_size, 1, threshold, &top_results, kTfLiteUInt8);
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot handle output type\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    // Print inference ms in input image
    cv::putText(frame, "Infernce Time in ms: " + std::to_string(inference_time), cv::Point(10, 30), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);

    // Load Labels
    auto labels = load_labels(labelFile);

    // Print labels with confidence in input image
    for (const auto &result : top_results)
    {
        const float confidence = result.first;
        const int index = result.second;
        std::string output_txt = "Label :" + labels[index] + " Confidence : " + std::to_string(confidence);
        cv::putText(frame, output_txt, cv::Point(10, 60), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    // Display image
    cv::imshow("Output", frame);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The lines affected :

```
104: tflite::label_image::get_top_n<float>(interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0), output_size, 1, threshold, &top_results, kTfLiteFloat32);
```

```
107: tflite::label_image::get_top_n<uint8_t>(interpreter->typed_output_tensor<uint8_t>(0), output_size, 1, threshold, &top_results, kTfLiteUInt8);
```

Content of `tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/get_top_n.h`:

```
/* Copyright 2017 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved. ...*/

#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_H_

#include "tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/get_top_n_impl.h"

namespace tflite {
namespace label_image {

template <class T>
void get_top_n(T* prediction, int prediction_size, size_t num_results,
               float threshold, std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>* top_results,
               TfLiteType input_type);

// explicit instantiation so that we can use them otherwhere
template void get_top_n<float>(float*, int, size_t, float,
                               std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>*, TfLiteType);
template void get_top_n<int8_t>(int8_t*, int, size_t, float,
                                std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>*,
                                TfLiteType);
template void get_top_n<uint8_t>(uint8_t*, int, size_t, float,
                                 std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>*,
                                 TfLiteType);

}  // namespace label_image
}  // namespace tflite

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_H_
```

Content of `tensorflow/lite/examples/label_image/get_top_n_impl.h`:

```
/* Copyright 2017 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved. ...*/

#ifndef TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_IMPL_H_
#define TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_IMPL_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

#include "tensorflow/lite/c/common.h"

namespace tflite {
namespace label_image {

extern bool input_floating;

// Returns the top N confidence values over threshold in the provided vector,
// sorted by confidence in descending order.
template <class T>
void get_top_n(T* prediction, int prediction_size, size_t num_results,
               float threshold, std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>* top_results,
               TfLiteType input_type) {
  // Will contain top N results in ascending order.
  std::priority_queue<std::pair<float, int>, std::vector<std::pair<float, int>>,
                      std::greater<std::pair<float, int>>>
      top_result_pq;

  const long count = prediction_size;  // NOLINT(runtime/int)
  float value = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    switch (input_type) {
      case kTfLiteFloat32:
        value = prediction[i];
        break;
      case kTfLiteInt8:
        value = (prediction[i] + 128) / 256.0;
        break;
      case kTfLiteUInt8:
        value = prediction[i] / 255.0;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    // Only add it if it beats the threshold and has a chance at being in
    // the top N.
    if (value < threshold) {
      continue;
    }

    top_result_pq.push(std::pair<float, int>(value, i));

    // If at capacity, kick the smallest value out.
    if (top_result_pq.size() > num_results) {
      top_result_pq.pop();
    }
  }

  // Copy to output vector and reverse into descending order.
  while (!top_result_pq.empty()) {
    top_results->push_back(top_result_pq.top());
    top_result_pq.pop();
  }
  std::reverse(top_results->begin(), top_results->end());
}

}  // namespace label_image
}  // namespace tflite

#endif  // TENSORFLOW_LITE_EXAMPLES_LABEL_IMAGE_GET_TOP_N_IMPL_H_
```

[Github link](https://github.com/topiga/tflite/tree/master/05_TFLite_Image_Classification/image_classification_tflite_opencv)

Comment: where's the error message? complete error output is required. -- is this a linker issue? did you forget to specify some libraries to the linker? just including some headers isn't enough...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz it is fixed, I forgot the error message, thanks

Comment: and which line is line 107, as named in the error message? -- why are you using **float** for the **int**32 case? that entire case contains a mix of float and int32, which will give you trouble.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz fixed, I added the headers too. I don't see where I use `int32`.

Comment: I haven't checked your edits to your question yet and can't possibly remember what text used to be there. -- one instance: `case kTfLiteInt32:` granted, that doesn't lead to type system errors but it's still a bug.